# Python, Surface between two curves, matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two numpy arrays that represent a line in 3d space (note

```
# this represents line 1
x1 = [1,2,3]
y1 = [1,4,4]
z1 = [1,1,1]

# this represents line 2
x2 = [1,2,3,4]
y2 = [1,4,5,7]
z2 = [10,10,10]



# Notice that the array representing line 1 and the array representing line 2 have different sizes
# I am currently plotting the aforementioned '3D' lines as follows
ax.plot(x1,y1,z1)
ax.plot(x2,y2,z2)
```

I want to plot  the surface that connects these lines in 3D to get something like this:

https://pythonprogramming.net/static/images/dataviz/wire-frame-plane-tutorial-matplotlib-python-1024x682.png

How can I do this using matplotlib in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have too few points to create a reasonable grid.

What you can do is using `plot_trisurf` to plot the points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# this represents line 1
x1 = [1,2,3]
y1 = [1,4,4]
z1 = [1,1,1]

# this represents line 2
x2 = [1,2,3,4]
y2 = [1,4,5,7]
z2 = [10,10,10,10]

# Notice that the array representing line 1 and the array representing line 2 have different sizes
# I am currently plotting the aforementioned '3D' lines as follows
ax.plot(x1,y1,z1)
ax.plot(x2,y2,z2)

x=np.array([1,2,3, 1,2,3,4])
y=np.array([1,4,4, 1,4,5,7])
z=np.array([1,1,1, 10,10,10,10])

ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z )

plt.show()
```

[image]

But the result is not really appealing.